# No me cargan las imagenes que cree en mi codigo mediante un array, alguien sabe a que se debe esto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Tengo una pregunta acerca de mi código. No me cargan las imagenes que cree en mi codigo mediante un array, alguien sabe a que se debe esto. Gracias

```
<div className="cont_C">  
                {
                  arrEnd.map((id:any, img:any)=>{
                    return(
                      <div className={values[img.toString()]} onClick={handlerClick} id={id?.val + "-" + (id).toString()}>
                      <img src={id?.img?.path}/>
                      </div>
                    )
                  }
                  )}
             </div>
```

```
const arrEnd= [
    { id: 1, img:bolsa10 [0]},
    { id: 2, img:bolsa11[1]},
    { id: 3, img:bolsa9[2]}
  ]
```

Anexo pantallazos de código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El codigo no debe ir en imagenes, las imagenes deben ser usadas como ilustraciones de algun concepto, mas no como codigo

Comment: No se entiende, tu arreglo _arrEnd_ tiene una estructura distinta a la que referencias en el componente. De dónde viene _path_? Dónde esta en tu arreglo _arrEnd_ ¿?